# How to 'Set <select> tag attributes From associative array php '?

Tags: php, html, associative-array

How to set the `<select>` tag attributes from an associative array dynamically?

I need to send custom attributes from array and check if name is passed as key from array.

For Example Array:

```
$custom_attr = array("id"=>"year1","name"=>"year","class"=>"dp year form-control")
```

Creating `<select>` tag like:

```
<select id="year1" name="year" class="dp year form-control">
.
.
.
</select>
```

Any idea about how to implement it? Thank you.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “I want” is not a problem description; you are supposed to show us what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
$result="<select ";
foreach($custom_attr as $key => $value){
    $result.=$key.' = "'.$value.'" ';
}
$result.=">";
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way. Here is a more elegant approach:

```
function getTag($tag, $attributes) {
    array_walk($attributes, function(&$val, $key) { $val = "$key='".htmlentities($val)."'"; });
    $attributes = implode(' ', $attributes);
    return "<$tag $attributes>";
}

echo getTag('select', array("id"=>"year1", "name"=>"year", "class"=>"dp year form-control"));
```